# Find these query results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Given This

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContactPosition](
    [ContactPositionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PositionId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ContactPosition] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContactPositionId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts](
    [ContactId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CONTACTS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lookup](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Topic] [varchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [PrimaryContactPosition] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SecondaryContactPosition] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ThirdContactPosition] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Lookup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (1, 1, 2)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (2, 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (3, 3, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (4, 4, 4)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (5, 5, 5)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (6, 6, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId], [ContactId], [PositionId]) VALUES (7, 7, 7)
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (1, N'John', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (2, N'Jane', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (3, N'Ed ', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (4, N'Ron', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (5, N'Janet', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (6, N'Chris', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId], [FirstName], [LastName]) VALUES (7, N'Russ', N'Doe')
INSERT [dbo].[Lookup] ([Id], [Topic], [PrimaryContactPosition], [SecondaryContactPosition], [ThirdContactPosition]) VALUES (1, N'Topic 1', 1, 2, 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Lookup] ([Id], [Topic], [PrimaryContactPosition], [SecondaryContactPosition], [ThirdContactPosition]) VALUES (2, N'Topic 2', 4, 5, 6)
INSERT [dbo].[Lookup] ([Id], [Topic], [PrimaryContactPosition], [SecondaryContactPosition], [ThirdContactPosition]) VALUES (3, N'Topic 3', 2, 5, 6)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactPosition]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactPosition_Contacts] FOREIGN KEY([ContactId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Contacts] ([ContactId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ContactPosition] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_ContactPosition_Contacts]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition] FOREIGN KEY([PrimaryContactPosition])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition1] FOREIGN KEY([SecondaryContactPosition])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition2] FOREIGN KEY([ThirdContactPosition])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ContactPosition] ([ContactPositionId])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Lookup] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Lookup_ContactPosition2]
GO
```

How can I get the FullName for Secondary and backup also.

```
SELECT Contacts.ContactId AS ContactId,
       ContactPosition.ContactPositionId,
       ContactPosition.PositionId,
       Lookup.Id,
       Lookup.Topic,
       Lookup.PrimaryContactPosition,
      Contacts.FirstName + ' ' + Contacts.LastName AS PrimaryFullName,
       Lookup.SecondaryContactPosition,
       Lookup.ThirdContactPosition
FROM Contacts
     INNER JOIN ContactPosition ON Contacts.ContactId = ContactPosition.ContactId
     INNER JOIN Lookup ON ContactPosition.ContactPositionId = Lookup.PrimaryContactPosition
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self join. Contacts is the table that has the FirstName and LastName fields. As you require names of multiple contacts in a single row, use self join on contacts table to get those name.

```
SELECT c1.ContactId AS ContactId,
           cp.ContactPositionId,
           cp.PositionId,
           l.Id,
           l.Topic,
           l.PrimaryContactPosition,
          c1.FirstName+' '+ c1.LastName AS PrimaryFullName,
           l.SecondaryContactPosition,
           c2.FirstName+' '+ c2.LastName AS SecondaryFullName,
           l.ThirdContactPosition,
           c3.FirstName+' '+ c3.LastName AS ThirdFullName
    FROM Contacts c1
         INNER JOIN ContactPosition cp ON c1.ContactId = cp.ContactId
         INNER JOIN Lookup l ON cp.ContactPositionId = l.PrimaryContactPosition
         INNER JOIN Contacts c2 ON c2.ContactId = l.SecondaryContactPosition
         INNER JOIN Contacts c3 ON c3.ContactId = l.ThirdContactPosition;
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with some explanation of the techniques you used and how it answers the question.

Comment: If the first instance of `Contacts` is linked to `Lookup` through `ContactPosition`, shouldn't you link `Lookup` to the other two instances of `Contacts` likewise? My understanding is you will need to join two more instances of `ContactPosition`, one for each of `c2` and `c3`.

Comment: Nope. Linking Lookup already gave you the primary, secondary and third contact positions for a contact ID. Now you need only the names of those IDs. ContactID being the primary key of Contacts fetches you the names for each of those IDs in a separate column. Try this query and see.

Comment: But you are matching `PrimaryContactPosition` with `ContactPositionId` which is a column of `ContactPosition`, while `SecondaryContactPosition` and `ThirdContactPosition` are being matched with `ContactId` which is a `Contacts` column. Can't you see an inconsistency there?

Comment: I agree with AndriyM. I doubt the query will give correct results for the second and third contacts.

Answer (score 3):

[ArtBajji's approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/200053/6965) is a step in the right direction, although it should be pointed out that there is no self-join involved and the implementation itself needs a little tweaking.

What is true is that you need to join the `Contacts` table repeatedly to get the contact names for all three positions. What is missing is that `ContactPosition` needs to be joined repeatedly too, because it is only through `ContactPosition` that you can get from `Lookup` to `Contacts` for each of the three references.

This is how I would implement it then:

```
SELECT
  LookupId                   = l.Id,
  PrimaryContactPositionId   = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  SecondaryContactPositionId = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  ThirdContactPositionId     = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  PrimaryContactId           = c1.ContactId,
  SecondaryContactId         = c2.ContactId,
  ThirdContactId             = c3.ContactId,
  PrimaryFullName            = c1.FirstName + ' ' + c1.LastName,
  SecondaryFullName          = c2.FirstName + ' ' + c2.LastName,
  ThirdFullName              = c3.FirstName + ' ' + c3.LastName
FROM
  dbo.Lookup AS l
  INNER JOIN dbo.ContactPosition AS cp1 ON l  .PrimaryContactPosition   = cp1.ContactPositionId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts        AS c1  ON cp1.ContactId                = c1 .ContactId
  INNER JOIN dbo.ContactPosition AS cp2 ON l  .SecondaryContactPosition = cp2.ContactPositionId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts        AS c2  ON cp2.ContactId                = c2 .ContactId
  INNER JOIN dbo.ContactPosition AS cp3 ON l  .ThirdContactPosition     = cp3.ContactPositionId
  INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts        AS c3  ON cp3.ContactId                = c3 .ContactId
;
```

I have rearranged the original joins slightly to make it more obvious that you need to join repeatedly both `Contacts` and `ContactPosition`. Note, however, that you can avoid repetition of the `JOIN ContactPosition JOIN Contacts` pattern with the help of a "local view", more widely known as [*common table expression* (CTE), or WITH clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql). You can implement the join in the CTE and then join repeatedly just the CTE:

```
WITH
  ContactFullNames AS
  (
    SELECT
      cp.ContactPositionId,
      c.ContactId,
      ContactFullName = c.FirstName + c.LastName
    FROM
      dbo.ContactPosition AS cp
      INNER JOIN dbo.Contact AS c ON cp.ContactId = c.ContactId
  )
SELECT
  LookupId                   = l.Id,
  PrimaryContactPositionId   = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  SecondaryContactPositionId = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  ThirdContactPositionId     = l.PrimaryContactPosition,
  PrimaryContactId           = cfn1.ContactId,
  SecondaryContactId         = cfn2.ContactId,
  ThirdContactId             = cfn3.ContactId,
  PrimaryFullName            = cfn1.ContactFullName,
  SecondaryFullName          = cfn2.ContactFullName,
  ThirdFullName              = cfn3.ContactFullName
FROM
  dbo.Lookup AS l
  INNER JOIN ContactFullNames AS cfn1 ON l.PrimaryContactPosition   = cfn1.ContactPositionId
  INNER JOIN ContactFullNames AS cfn2 ON l.SecondaryContactPosition = cfn2.ContactPositionId
  INNER JOIN ContactFullNames AS cfn3 ON l.ThirdContactPosition     = cfn3.ContactPositionId
;
```

Effectively this is the same as the previous query: eliminating the repetitive join pattern in the code most likely will not prevent the repetitions in the actual plan. However, the code is arguably clearer to understand this way.